# ajax brakes on xmlHttp.readysate

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm new in ajax but now i got a problem with my script in ajax. I'm using code:

```
    var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp;

    if(windows.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if (!xmlHttp) {
        alert('Cant create object hoss!');
    } else {
        return xmlHttp;
    }
}

function process() {
    alert('State is: ' + xmlHttp.readyState);
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
        alert('Process is ready!');
        food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food=" + food, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    } else { 
        alert('Process is not ready!');
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}
```

I have debug my process() and i found that if im using first alert without xmlHttp.readyState so its shows to me messagebox other way if i add xmlhttp not works and if i comment my first alert in process() other 2 alerts not respone anything at all.

Maybe a have made some mistakes or maybe some problems with my web server i'm using xampp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a javascript debugger, like the one available in google chrome.

You will find that the alerts don't show because xmlHttp.readyState is undefined. Since there is an error in that line of code (undefined variable) the alert won't show.

The reason it is undefined is because it is in function scope. Your `process` function will never be able to see variables inside your `createXmlHttpRequestObject` function.

Once quick, albeit inelegant solution would be to make xmlHTTP a global variable, and not redeclare it in each function.

Comment: I have a bit more test and i found that, when i starting process() function my xmlHttp status is undefind.